# Cordova Media Plugin Breaks HTML5 Video

Tags: ios, cordova, video, media, audio-recording

If I use The Cordova Media Plugin to record an audio file,
on iOS it will break all HTML5 Video elements on the page
so they cannot get played anymore.
The same issue was posted here some month ago:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/KWzeeNflJ4g

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this work you have to create the entry in the file System before recording